# Как устроена семантика перемещения?

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Не понимаю, как работает перемещение на уровне ассемблера?

Ведь в ассемблере нет операции перемещения, но получается что перемещение быстрее.

Как так?

Comment: Я сначала ничего не понял, а потом ещё немножечко не понял.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Нет никакой "семантики перемещения" на уровне ассемблера.

Семантика перемещения - это абстрактная высокоуровневая концепция, т.е. концепция уровня языка, которая опирается на концепции категорий выражений (lvalue, rvalue, xvalue) и на сопутствующие правила разрешения перегрузки (overload resolution). С точки зрения производительности, цель семантики перемещения - организовать на уровне языка поддержку безопасного выбора между выполнением дорогого "глубокого" (deep) копирования или дешевого "мелкого" (shallow) *копирования*.

Получающийся в результате машинный код ничем не отличается от машинного кода, который мы получали и раньше, до появления в языке семантики перемещения. Просто раньше мы реализовывали семантику перемещения "вручную", а теперь ее поддержка появилась на уровне языка.